TikZ node inside `msccomment` throws `doesn't match its definition` error
I have a protocol in msc where each message has the step (1, 2, 3, etc) next to it. This is done using a \msccomment command.
Example: \msccomment[draw=none, msccomment distance=0cm, side=left]{12}{a}.
Now I'm replacing those steps with a TikZ node in order to make it look better. For example, replacing 12 above with \numd{12}. But this is throwing an error.

I've removed everything I could from the sequence diagram, including multiple options from the \numd newcommand, to try and spot the error but this is beyond my understanding of latex.
Using documentclass report doesn't help either.
Removing the optional argument from \numd doesn't help. (In any case, I need it to set the steps.)
The error occurs only when using \msccomment{\numd{1}}{a}. Using \msccomment{1}{a} in the sequence diagram does work.
The new command \numd works if I place it in a \mess, but I want it in the \msccomment.

Error
! Use of \msc@msccomment@opt doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.14    \msccomment{\numd{1}}{a}
                                % this version DOES NOT work: problem is here

Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{msc}

\newcommand*{\numd}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node [minimum size=0.5cm, fill=blue, text=white, font=\libertineSB\scriptsize] (char) {#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{}
    \declinst{a}{}{A}
    \declinst{v}{}{V}

    % DOESN'T WORK Problem in msccomment because of \numd{1} but works if only `1` without `\numd`
    \msccomment{\numd{1}}{a}  % this version DOES NOT work: problem is here
    %\msccomment{1}{a}  % this version works
    \mess{\numd{1} $x$}{a}{v}
    \nextlevel

\end{msc}
\end{document}


Update · More Context
To give more context, I'm using \numd{n} in the sequence diagram and in the text. Example:

A sends $x$ to V \numd{1}, then V does (...) and replies with y \numd{2}.

I know it might look a bit unstylish with the squared blue boxes in the MWE but that's because I simplified the code when posting the question (I wasn't sure how much to remove from the original source code, and the style itself didn't seem relevant to the problem I was having).
For the curious, the \numd I'm using (which is itself adapted from an answer on tex.SE) is:
\newcommand*{\numd}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node [solid, rounded rectangle, minimum size=0.3cm, inner sep=0cm, text height=1ex, text depth=0.1ex, fill=magenta!25!black, text=white, font=\libertineSB\scriptsize] (char) {#1}}}

which looks like:

when invoked with:
\msccomment[draw=none, msccomment distance=0cm, side=left]{\noexpand\numd{3}}{a}
\mess{$\var{E}$}{a}{v}
\nextlevel

Adding the \noexpand as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714739/54103 solves the issue I was having.

Nesting tikzpictures is not supported and frequently breaks. This breaks. Redefine the macro so it doesn't do \tikz{}. Maybe something from the tikzmark library would work here - it has macros for inserting nodes into nodes in tikzpictures. Or just a \node might work.

By checking the source code. The first argument in \msccomment will be expanded defined using \edef. So to make the \numd code working you need put \noexpand in front of it. See this example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{msc}

\newcommand{\numd}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node [minimum size=0.5cm, fill=blue, text=white, font=\libertineSB\scriptsize] (char) {#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{}
\declinst{a}{}{A}
\declinst{v}{}{V}
\msccomment{\noexpand\numd{1}}{a}
\end{msc}
\end{document}


output:


But I don't think this is what you wanted. Because by default 1 will in a node. You actually put the new node inside the previous node.
What you can do is to direct format the default node style as you wanted using the optional arguments before the 1, like this:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{}
\declinst{a}{}{A}
\declinst{v}{}{V}
\msccomment[%
fill=blue,
text=white,
minimum size=0.5cm,
font=\noexpand\libertineSB\noexpand\scriptsize,
every msccomment/.append style={draw=none}%
]{1}{a}
\end{msc}
\end{document}


Output:



Formatting the default node style of \msccomment as you suggest seems like a better option but in my case I'm using \numd in i) figures and in ii) text, so I feel that it makes more sense in this case to use the \noexpand. Easier to change \numd and have it applied everywhere (both figures and text) if the need arises. I've added more context to the question.
